# MongoDB .Net Driver - Pull multiple elements from arrays that exist in multiple documents

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have this code that pulls multiple elements from the 'fruits' array and it does it for all the 'stores' in the database:

```
db.stores.update(
  { },
  { $pull: { fruits: { $in: [ "apples", "bananas" ] } } },
  { multi: true }
)
```

How can I transfer this to C# code using .Net Driver?
`UpdateManyAsync` method should be used from namespace MongoDB.Driver `IMongoCollection` but I don't know how to do the specific filtering.

Comment: mongo driver allows implicit conversion between string and most of parameters, so you can just put a string `{ $pull: { fruits: { $in: [ "apples", "bananas" ] } } }` into appropriate `UpdateManyAsync` argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo .NET driver support scripting with [untyped document (`BsonDocument`)](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/tree/master#untyped-documents).

[`UpdateMany`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/apidocs/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_UpdateMany.htm)

> Update many documents, equivalent to `{ multi: true }`

You can achieve as below:

```cs
MongoClient _client = new MongoClient("mongo connection string");

IMongoDatabase _database = _client.GetDatabase("your DB");
IMongoCollection<Store> _collection = _database.GetCollection<Store>("store");

string[] removedFruits = new string[] { "apples", "bananas" };
FilterDefinition<Store> filter = Builders<Store>.Filter.Empty;

UpdateDefinition<Store> update =
    new BsonDocument("$pull",
        new BsonDocument("fruits",
            new BsonDocument("$in", BsonArray.Create(removedFruits))
        )
    );

_collection.UpdateMany(filter, update);
```

```cs
public class Store
{
    public string[] Fruits { get; set; }

    // Other properties
}
```

Comment: This solution solved the probelm, thank you very much :)